# Why does an Akka stream has exactly one source and sink?

Tags: akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

Akka Streams docs clearly state that in order for a stream to be runnable it must have *exactly* one source and *exactly* one sink. I wonder what imposes such constraint. Scenarios with multiple sources merged into one multiple sinks forked from a single stream are all very reasonable. Are there any technical reasons back such restriction?

Comment: Inability to implement backpressure in such scenario is one reason that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you refer to [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#Defining_and_running_streams) documentation section, which defines the fundamental components of Akka Streams:

> **Source**: A processing stage with exactly one output, [...]
>
> **Sink**: A processing stage with exactly one input, [...]
>
> **Flow**: A processing stage which has exactly one input and output, [...]
>
> **RunnableGraph**: A Flow that has both ends "attached" to a Source and Sink respectively, and is ready to be `run()`.

Now whereas the first 3 definitions are clear and truthful, I think the definition of `RunnableGraph` is incomplete. A `RunnableGraph` can be defined as described (i.e. `source.via(flow).to(sink)`), and this is the simplest way you can get one of those. However, there are more flexible and complex ways to define `RunnableGraph`s, for example the [GraphDSL](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html).

If you check out the examples in [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html#Constructing_and_combining_Partial_Graphs) section, you'll see `RunnableGraph`s built up from multiple sources and/or multiple sinks.

It's probably more accurate to say that a `RunnableGraph` is a processing stage with no inputs and no outputs (i.e. has a `ClosedShape`).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, I was referring to those definitions, and it's the definition of a RunnableGraph as a graph connecting a single source to a single sink via flows that left me confused. Now it's clear.